# Microsoft XML Parser 3.0

Tags: xml, parsing

There is an application where I work that uses the Microsoft XML parser 3.0. I couldn't find any documentation about it and that's becoming a problem, because we cannot use this web application with Firefox, Safari and etc. Am I wrong?

Can we install the XML parser 3.0 in different browsers?

Who can i find a documentation about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resources:**

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx)
- [MSXML Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSXML)

> Can we install the XML parser 3.0 in different browsers?

No. MSXML is an ActiveX-object, so it is only supported in IE.

But there are equivalents for other browsers. You will have to provide more details if you want to know how to convert your MSXML-based code into cross-platform code.